# Strange behavior of simple For loop in C language

Tags: c, for-loop, turbo-c

I was just curious to do it and find the result, but I got really shocked...

Actually,

when we do this:

```
for(i=0; 0; i++)
 printf("hello");
```

**it prints hello.**.. which it should not.

and if do like this:

```
int a=0;
for(i=0;a;i++)
 printf("hello");
```

**it doesn't print hello.**..

although the **expected behavior is shown in if-else or while loop**..
Can anyone explain?

Comment: What compiler are you using and what system are you on? I can not reproduce the first one.

Comment: windows 7, turbo-c using dos-box

Comment: Are you sure you didn't type `for(i=0; 0; i++);` by mistake?

Comment: Maybe some issues outside the shown code? In C, it's possible to modify things on the stack unintentionally, for example.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the example, or did you retype it from memory? I suspect you had an extra `;` at the end of the first line of your first snippet.

Comment: Try to copy-paste your code to https://ideone.com and see if it reproduces there, if so, give us the link (putting your complete source (copy-pasted, not rewritten) as is in the question is always a good idea; if it's too long, you should construct an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @unwind No i didn't.. i am sure.. although it gives me a warning that the code is unreachable.. then also it prints hello

Comment: @Dukeling I would not have even thought to look but you actually found a dup that looks like it explains this!

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour  but i didn't get how that is relevant or explaining my question..

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt The compiler is buggy, that's it.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt if you read all the answers and comments the consensus is that it is a bug and I would agree.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour ok thanks a lot... i thought it's some kind of a deep concept...:)